# Printing integers passed as arguments in function in C

Tags: c, integer, printf

I am very new to C programming and having trouble compiling what should be a very simple function. The function, called printSummary, simply takes 3 integers as arguments, then prints some text along with those integers. For example, if hits=1, misses=2, and evictions=3, then printSummary(hits,misses,evictions) should print the following:

hits:1 misses:2 evictions:3

Here is the code I'm using. Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printSummary(int hits, int misses, int evictions)
{
    printf('hits: %d\n');
    printf('misses: %d\n');
    printf('evictions: %d\n');
}

int main()
{
    int hit_count = 1;
    int miss_count = 2;
    int eviction_count = 3;
    printSummary(hit_count, miss_count, eviction_count);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code gives me several warnings, but no errors. When I run the code, I get a segmentation fault. Like I said, I am fairly new to C so there is most likely a simply solution that I am just missing. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Step 1 `'hits: %d\n'` --> `"hits: %d\n"`  " vs '

Comment: Please always list warnings and errors you get. “gives me several warnings” is a nice thing to know, but ultimately useless unless you tell us what warnings you received.

Comment: Changing ' to " worked. Is there a reason they work differently?

Comment: `'a'` in C is the notation for a character literal whereas `"abc"` is a string literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the below changes .

```
   printf("hits: %d\n",hits);
   printf("misses: %d\n",misses);
   printf("evictions: %d\n",evictions);
```

printf has a

```
int printf(const char *format, ...)
```

prototype. So in the first argument you can pass format specifiers and in the next provide the actual variables/values to be printed out

Comment: Would you mind explaining what OP did wrong so he can undestand and learn?

Comment: I had thought that using %d just used to already given arguments in order. Didn't realize I had to specify them.

Answer (score 1):

errors are:

```
void printSummary(int hits, int misses, int evictions)
{
    /* Name: printf
    Prototype: int printf (const char *template, ...)
    Description:
    The printf function prints the optional arguments under the
     control of the template string template to the stream stdout. 
    It returns the number of characters printed,or a negative value if
     there was an output error.*/

    printf("hits: %d\n", hits); // don't use ' it is used only for char variable for example: char a = 'c';
    printf("misses: %d\n", misses);
    printf("evictions: %d\n", evictions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your printf function is not being called correctly. You have to include the integers needed to print:

```
printf("hits: %d\n", hits);
printf("misses: %d\n", misses);
printf("evictions: %d\n", evictions);
```

Read more about the printf function [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm).

Comment: I had tried that before but I was still getting a bunch of warnings. Doing what you suggested and changing the ' to " seems to have worked though. Do ' and " have different meanings?

Comment: It was just explained to me that ' is used for characters while " is used for strings in C

Comment: Ahhh I see now...I needed to change the ' to ". I've edited my answer.